# If-Else List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

So now I have three lists:

```
list1 = [False if num1[i] == '0' else True for i in range(len(num1))]
list2 = [False if num2[i] == '0' else True for i in range(len(num2))]
tmp = [False for i in range(abs(len(list1)-len(list2)))]
```

And I want to combine the lists under these conditions:

```
if len(list1) > len(list2):
    list2 = tmp + list2
else:
    list1 = tmp + list1
```

Is there any way that I am able to do all these processes using list comprehension? Especially that `if-else` part when combining the `tmp` list with `list1` and `list2` (Python3.7)

Comment: What are `num1` and `num2`? Might be able to optimise that, too.

Comment: Actually, if you could explain why you want to do this, we might be able to come up with an even better solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, `list1` and `list2` should have the same length as `num1` and `num2`. Also, you can simplify your statements a little bit:

```
result = [False] * abs(len(num1) - len(num2)) + [num != '0' for num in min(num2, num1, key=len)]
```

`result` will be whatever list you wanted to add `temp` to. This assumes you won't need both `list1` and `list2` in the future. Of course, you can easily construct them if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can take the longest length and fill it if exceeds for example:

```
list_length = max(len(num1), len(num2))
list1 = [i < len(num1) and num1[i] != '0' for i in range(list_length)]
list2 = [i < len(num2) and num2[i] != '0' for i in range(list_length)]
```

Note I also simplified `False if num2[i] == '0' else True` to `num2[i] != '0'`.